# Powershell remove space from after command

Tags: powershell

I have this command

```
Write-Host "Background " -NoNewline; [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]
    ::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;  Write-Host "x" -NoNewline; 
          [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
```

I want it to come out Background 1920x1080

I cant seem to find a way to stop the command

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
```

from making a new line.

Its coming out

Background 1920

x1080

Comment: @RyanBemrose: while Jeffrey's article addresses the use of Write-Host, it doesn't do anything to help him figure out his string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less complicated to simply use string formatting or in-line expand into a single string.

```
"Background {0}x{1}" -f [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
```

or

```
Write-Host "Background $([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width)x$([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height)"
```

An article on various formatting options: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/12/use-powershell-to-format-strings-with-composite-formatting/

The reason you're getting the extra newline is that your code sample omitted a Write-Host on the Width portion.  The first items went to Write-Host, then an item on the output stream that didn't have a way to omit the newline.  Simply correcting that flaw gives you the output you desired, but the approach is overly complicated.

Fixed original sample:

```
Write-Host "Background " -NoNewline;
Write-Host ([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width) -NoNewLine;  
Write-Host "x" -NoNewline; 
Write-Host ([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple lines because you are not calling `Write-Host -NoNewLine` on the command to output the width.  Your code is running the following four commands

```
Write-Host "Background " -NoNewline
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
Write-Host "x" -NoNewline
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
```

The second and fourth commands insert a newline, because you didn't use `Write-Host` to tell them not to.

`Write-Host` is [not usually the best way](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) to output text.  A better option would be to build the output string in one statement using PowerShell's `-f` formatting operator.

```
$width = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
$height = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
"Background {0}x{1}" -f ($width, $height)
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.